# virtualenv bug?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I am trying to run the following script in my virtualenv:

```
(python2.7.2-gonvaled1)gonvaled@lycaon:~/.virtualenvs/python2.7.2-gonvaled1$ couchy.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gonvaled/projects/bin/couchy.py", line 46, in <module>
    from   couchdb_support           import CouchdbLists
  File "/home/gonvaled/projects/test_project/python_modules/couchdb_support.py", line 3615, in <module>
    from   asterisk_support          import AsteriskSupport
  File "/home/gonvaled/projects/test_project/python_modules/asterisk_support.py", line 4, in <module>
    from   starpy_support                   import AmiCommand
  File "/home/gonvaled/projects/test_project/python_modules/starpy_support.py", line 7, in <module>
    from   starpy                    import manager, fastagi, utilapplication, menu
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/starpy/utilapplication.py", line 2, in <module>
    from basicproperty import common, propertied, basic, weak
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/basicproperty-0.6.12a-py2.5-linux-i686.egg/basicproperty/common.py", line 159, in <module>
    from basictypes import datedatetime_types as ddt
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/basicproperty-0.6.12a-py2.5-linux-i686.egg/basictypes/datedatetime_types.py", line 4, in <module>
    from dateutil import parser 
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/python_dateutil-2.1-py2.5.egg/dateutil/parser.py", line 8
    from __future__ import unicode_literals
SyntaxError: future feature unicode_literals is not defined
```

So somehow python is trying to import from:

```
/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/starpy/utilapplication.py
```

This does not make any sense. My virtualenv is very clean:

```
(python2.7.2-gonvaled1)gonvaled@lycaon:~/.virtualenvs/python2.7.2-gonvaled1$ python
Python 2.7.2 (default, Mar 29 2012, 00:31:29) 
[GCC 4.2.4 (Ubuntu 4.2.4-1ubuntu4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path   
['', '/home/gonvaled/.virtualenvs/python2.7.2-gonvaled1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg', '/home/gonvaled/.virtualenvs/python2.7.2-gonvaled1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg', '/home/gonvaled/.virtualenvs/python2.7.2-gonvaled1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Twisted-12.0.0-py2.7-linux-i686.egg', '/home/gonvaled/.virtualenvs/python2.7.2-gonvaled1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zope.interface-3.8.0-py2.7-linux-i686.egg', '/home/gonvaled/.virtualenvs/python2.7.2-gonvaled1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/basicproperty-0.6.12a-py2.7-linux-i686.egg', '/home/gonvaled/projects/gonvaled_settings', '/home/gonvaled/django_apps', '/home/gonvaled/projects/test_project/ipc', '/home/gonvaled/projects/test_project/python_modules', '/home/gonvaled/projects/test_project/gdata', '/home/gonvaled/projects/callisto/libraries', '/home/gonvaled/.virtualenvs/python2.7.2-gonvaled1', '/home/gonvaled/.virtualenvs/python2.7.2-gonvaled1/lib/python27.zip', '/home/gonvaled/.virtualenvs/python2.7.2-gonvaled1/lib/python2.7', '/home/gonvaled/.virtualenvs/python2.7.2-gonvaled1/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/home/gonvaled/.virtualenvs/python2.7.2-gonvaled1/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/home/gonvaled/.virtualenvs/python2.7.2-gonvaled1/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/home/gonvaled/.virtualenvs/python2.7.2-gonvaled1/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7', '/usr/local/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/local/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/home/gonvaled/.virtualenvs/python2.7.2-gonvaled1/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

And:

```
(python2.7.2-gonvaled1)gonvaled@lycaon:~/.virtualenvs/python2.7.2-gonvaled1$ pip freeze
CouchDB==0.9dev
DateUtils==0.5.1
Twisted==12.0.0
basicproperty==0.6.12a
pystache==0.4.0
python-dateutil==2.1
pytz==2012b
simplejson==2.4.0
six==1.1.0
starpy==1.0.0a12
wsgiref==0.1.2
zope.interface==3.8.0
```

So to summarize: python is importing from `/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages` even though I am inside a virtualenv. How can this be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running the script as:

```
$ python couch.py
```

in your activated virtualenv.  Depending on your system and the first line (the shebang line) of the file, you may not be running in the Python you think you are.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. My shebang is `#!/usr/bin/python`. I find a bit annoying that I can not run my python scripts by themselves. It means that, to run them in a virtualenv, I must do something different than what I do in the host environment. It effectively kills the concept of shebang, since to make this general, I can not rely on it (think control scripts, cronjobs, etc). I have tried to put `#!python` in the shebang, but apparently absolute paths are required.

Comment: Use a shebang line of `#!/usr/bin/env python` . That should use the first `python` found on the current `$PATH` which should be the one in your active virtualenv.

Answer (score 0):

You should create your virtualenv with the `--nositepackages` option to keep it clean and away from your system Python.

Comment: No, no, I already said that my virtualenv was *very* clean. It was actually created using `--nositepackages` (which, by the way, is no longer required in recent versions of virtualenv, since it has become the default)